# navigator.geolocation.watchPosition not working on Samsung Galaxy Xcover - GPS stays off

Tags: geolocation, gps, sencha-touch-2, cordova

I have an application written in javascript, using Sencha Touch and Cordova libraries. It is a mobile application for Android devices.

I use `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition()` to get a GPS position. My code works on other phones that I have tested (HTC one X, LG optimus black, LG optimus 2X, HTC evo 3D and a few others), but not on Samsung Galaxy Xcover S5690.

The problem is that the GPS is never turned on on the Xcover, so that at best I only get a very inaccurate position (probably based on mobile towers). On other devices the GPS icon on the status bar starts blinking and eventually I get a very accurate position.

My manifest file is OK (`ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` line), my plugins.xml is OK (cordova.GeoBroker line). The GPS just stays turned off.

I am using ST 2.0 and Cordova 2.0. I call `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition()` from my `onDeviceReady()` listener. And my code works on other phones and on Chrome browser.

Comment: I contacted Samsung support directly and I was informed that the HTML5 Geolocation API of Galaxy Xcover S5690 will be fixed in the next OS update, but it might take "a few weeks"... and no work-arounds, it just doesn't work until then.

Comment: Intersting, I didn't know that. Is there possible to use native code for that.